# Good example of web-based application that works on tablets?

Tags: html, layout, mobile

Does anyone know of any good examples of web based applications that uses one layout/code-base that works well on both normal browsers and tablets? The best mobile-compatible web application that I know of (app.ft.com, google-services), switches to a completely different code-base when accessing it from mobile devices.

We're developing a web-based application, but would like to avoid building a mobile version (as much as possible), but rather focusing on making the ordinary web application as mobile-compatible as possible in in order to keep the code-base simple.

I'm looking for good examples of navigation and structure that works in both worlds.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can ask people for lists of good examples (I'm not looking for a debate of what's good, I'm just looking for different examples)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) this is a HTML 5 framework that incorporates responsive design to ensure any websites that uses it looks great on all devices.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm quite familiar with boostrap and although I was looking for more real-life examples, I did find the site http://builtwithbootstrap.com/ so I'll start by looking there

Comment: great, this is my most recent bootsrap website for a local school -> http://www.arnoldacademy.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) which also supports web browsers down to and including Internet Explorer 7.

I have recently built a web app using one code base that runs on desktop browsers and mobiles, and also used [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to build installable apps for both Android and iOS.

Comment: This is actually what I would like to avoid, our first version of the application was built using jQuery Mobile, but we felt that we ended up with a code base that was too locked in to the jQuery Mobile framework and with an end-result of one code based for mobile users and another one for standard browsers. Furthermore, we felt that jQuery mobile was too buggy when trying to combine it with other types of html-based components like charts and other interactive javascript tools.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, fair enough.